# SQL query to extract overlaps between records BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, overlap

I am trying to construct a query from the below data:

```
time    user_id adver_id    tactic_id
time1   123 adv1    tac1
time2   123 adv1    tac1
time3   123 adv1    tac2
time4   124 adv1    tac1
time6   125 adv2    tac3
time7   123 adv2    tac1
```

The intended result should look like this:

```
    adver_id    adver_id_overlap    tactic_id   tactic_id_overlap   unique_users    total_records
    adv1    adv1    tac1    tac1    2   3
    adv1    adv1    tac1    tac2    1   2
    adv1    adv2    tac1    tac1    1   2
...
```

I have tried this query:

```
WITH adver_id_subquery AS
(
SELECT
user_id,
adver_id AS adver_id
FROM dataset1
GROUP BY user_id, adver_id
),
tactic_id_subquery AS
(
SELECT
user_id,
tactic_id AS tactic_id
FROM dataset1
GROUP BY user_id, tactic_id
)
SELECT
table1.adver_id AS adver_id, table1.adver_id AS adver_id_overlap, table2.tactic_id AS tactic_id, table2.tactic_id AS tactic_id_overlap, 
COUNT(*) AS unique_users
FROM adver_id_subquery AS table1
CROSS JOIN tactic_id_subquery AS table2
WHERE table1.user_id = table2.user_id 
GROUP BY adver_id,adver_id_overlap, tactic_id, tactic_id_overlap  
ORDER BY adver_id,adver_id_overlap, tactic_id, tactic_id_overlap
```

But the result is a bit different than I needed:

```
adver_id    adver_id_overlap    tactic_id   tactic_id_overlap   unique_users
adv1    adv1    tac1    tac1    2
adv1    adv1    tac2    tac2    1
adv2    adv2    tac1    tac1    1
adv2    adv2    tac2    tac2    1
adv2    adv2    tac3    tac3    1
```

This above result seems to only have duplicates row such as: adv1-adv2, tac1-tac1, tac2-tac2 etc. I would like to see overlaps such as: tac1-tac2, tac2-tac3 etc. Also, I am unable to get the total_records. Count(*) seems to result in unique_users.

I appreciate any help in getting the required result.

Comment: Please explain the logic for your desired results.  What does "overlap" mean?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, This is to show the overlap between different adver_id, Tactics in respect to unique users who were targeted and the total records. For example, I would be able to see that tact1 and tact2 were seen by 2 unique users and the total records we have is 3. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You comment suggests that you want a self join and aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select d1.adveri_d, as adverid1, d2.adver_id as adverid2,
       d1.tactic_id as tactic_1, d2.tactic as tactic_2,
       count(*) as num_overlaps,
       count(distinct users) as num_users
from dataset1 d1 join
     dataset2 d2
     on d1.adver_id <> d2.adver_id or
        d1.tactic_id <> d2.tactic_id
group by 1, 2, 3, 4
```